# CXF and Notification Operation

Tags: wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

In WSDL 1.1 specification, we have 4 operation type :

- One-way : "wsdl:input" **only**
- Request-response : "wsdl:input",
  "wsdl:output" and "wsdl:fault"
- Solicit-response : "wsdl:output",
  "wsdl:input" and "wsdl:fault"
- Notification : "wsdl:output" **only**

Using Apache CXF V3.2.0 and i try to generate Client (wsdl2java) from existing WSDL in what we have Notification operation with only "wsdl:output" in "wsdl:operation" :

```
<wsdl:operation name="NotifyMe">
    <wsdl:output action="myPort/NotifyMe" message="tns:myPort_NotifyMe_Output" />
</wsdl:operation>
```

i had this error during build :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.0:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project soap-callback: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.0:wsdl2java failed:
[ERROR] Summary:  Failures: 1, Warnings: 0
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] <<< ERROR!
[ERROR] Invalid WSDL, Operation NotifyMe in PortType {myPort} not request-response or one-way
```

How i solve this error and generate Client class from this WSDL ? Apache CXF support It Notification Operations ?

Answer (score 0):

Though WSDL 1.1 specification has defined 4 types of operational types, WSDL definition is validated as per the rules defined in WS-I Basic Profile.

WS-I Basic Profile - Rule R2303 has restriction to Solicit-response & Notification.

Here's a different error message from a different utility (MS's wsdl.exe) that explains the same thing a bit more thoroughly

> Warning: This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1.
>   R2303: A DESCRIPTION MUST NOT use Solicit-Response and Notification type operations in a wsdl:portType definition. Solicit-Response and Notification operations are not well defined by WSDL 1.1; furthermore, WSDL 1.1 does not define bindings for them.